# SPSS: using IF function with REPEAT when each case has multiple linked instances

Tags: loops, if-statement, linked-list, repeat, spss

I have a dataset as such:

```
Case #|DateA |Drug.1|Drug.2|Drug.3|DateB.1 |DateB.2  |DateB.3 |IV.1|IV.2|IV.3
------|------|------|------|------|--------|---------|--------|----|----|----
1     |DateA1|    X |    Y |    X |DateB1.1|DateB1.2 |DateB1.3| 1  |  0 | 1
2     |DateA2|    X |    Y |    X |DateB2.1|DateB2.2 |DateB2.3| 1  |  0 | 1
3     |DateA3|    Y |    Z |    X |DateB3.1|DateB3.2 |DateB3.3| 0  |  0 | 1
4     |DateA4|    Z |    Z |    Z |DateB4.1|DateB4.2 |DateB4.3| 0  |  0 | 0
```

For each case, there are linked variables i.e. Drug.1 is linked with DateB.1 and IV.1 (Indicator Variable.1); Drug.2 is linked with DateB.2 and IV.2, etc.

The variable IV.1 only = 1 if Drug.1 is the case that I want to analyze (in this example, I want to analyze each receipt of Drug "X"), and so on for the other IV variables. Otherwise, IV = 0 if the drug for that scenario is not "X".

I want to calculate the difference between DateA and DateB for each instance where Drug "X" is received.

e.g. In the example above I want to calculate a new variable:

```
DateDiffA1_B1.1 = DateA1 - DateB1.1
DateDiffA1_B2.1 = DateA1 - DateB2.1
DateDiffA1_B1.3 = DateA1 - DateB1.3
DateDiffA1_B2.3 = DateA1 - DateB2.3
DateDiffA1_B3.3 = DateA1 - DateB3.3
```

I'm not sure if this new variable would need to be linked to each instance of Drug "X" as for the other variables, or if it could be a single variable that COUNTS all the instances for each case.

The end goal is to COUNT how many times each case had a date difference of <= 2 weeks when they received Drug "X". If they did not receive Drug "X", I do not want to COUNT the date difference.

I will eventually want to compare those who did receive Drug "X" with a date difference <= 2 weeks to those who did not, so having another indicator variable to help separate out these specific patients would be beneficial.

I am unsure about the best way to go about this; I suspect it will require a combination of IF and REPEAT functions using the IV variable, but I am relatively new with SPSS and syntax and am not sure how this should be coded to avoid errors.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: It seems like I may need to use IV as a vector variable to loop through the linked variables in each case. I've tried the syntax below to no avail:

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
vector IV = IV.1 to IV.3.
    loop #i = .1 to .3.
do repeat DateB = DateB.1 to DateB.3 
                / DrugDateDiff = DateDiff.1 to DateDiff.3.
    if IV(#i) = 1
    / DrugDateDiff = datediff(DateA, DateB, "days").
end repeat.
end loop.
execute.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no need to add the vector and the loop, all you need can be done within one `DO REPEAT`:

```
compute N2W=0.
do repeat DateB = DateB.1 to DateB.3 /IV=IV.1 to IV.3 .
    if IV=1 and datediff(DateA, DateB, "days")<=14 N2W = N2W + 1.
end repeat.
execute.
```

This syntax will first put a zero in the count variable `N2W`. Then it will loop through all the dates, and only if the matching `IV` is 1, the syntax will compare them to `dateA`, and add 1 to the count if the difference is <=2 weeks.

if you prefer to keep the count variable as missing when none of the IV are 1, instead of `compute N2W=0.` start the syntax with:

```
If any(1, IV.1 to IV.3) N2W=0.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer eli-k!

I've used your code with the modification of trying to include an extra variable which gives the absolute datediff, before moving to the step of counting those <= 2 weeks:

`if any(1, IV.1 to IV.3) DrugDateDiff = 0.
do repeat DateB = DateB.1 to DateB.3
/ IV = IV.1 to IV.3
/ DrugDateDiff = DrugDateDiff.1 to DrugDateDiff.3.
if IV = 1
/ DrugDateDiff = datediff(DateA, DateB, "days").
end repeat.
execute.`
However, when I run this it says the DrugDateDiff variable is not previously defined.

Comment: I want to create a variable each time IV.1 up to IV.3 = 1, i.e. DrugDateDiff.1 to DrugDateDiff.3 if each IV = 1.

Comment: (1) you're using `DrugDateDiff` twice - once as your counting variable and once in the `DO REPEAT' command. Just change one of them. (2) Remove the "/" in the `IF` command.